# Backward search and replace using sed

Tags: regex, perl, sed

How to search for the last occurrence of a particular word/pattern in a string and replace it with an another word?

For example, Search word is `aaa` and Replace word is `zzz`

Input: `aaa bbb ccc bbb aaa`

Desired Output: `aaa bbb ccc bbb zzz`

`s/aaa/zzz/` replaces first word. Is there any additional option to search reverse?

Comment: given your example, you can anchor the search pattern to the end of the line, i.e. `echo "aaa bbb ccc bbb aaa" | sed 's/aaa$/zzz/'`, but this is what is known as a fragile solution. (You can account for extra spaces at end of line with `'s/aaa[ ]*$/zzz/'`. , but still fragile;-) ). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter what if I want to replace last occurrence of `bbb` with `yyy` next? :P

Comment: thats why I said this was a fragile solution, at peril from changing specifications ;-). Glad you got an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Using sed:

```
x='aaa bbb ccc bbb aaa'
sed 's/\(.*\)bbb/\1zzz/' <<< "$x"

aaa bbb ccc zzz aaa
```

#### Using perl command line:

sed doesn't support lookarounds so if you want to give perl a chance:

```
perl -pe 's/aaa(?!.*?aaa)/zzz/' <<< "$x"

aaa bbb ccc bbb zzz
```

Comment: Isn't this ugly? I mean I expected some switch or option just to search reverse. Also in the terms of performance for very long lines, won't this actually search in an entire string?

Comment: Ugly??? At least it does the job without writing some complicated command. How long is really your line?

Comment: Your solution work perfectly. No argument to that. I was asking just out of curiosity. I haven't counted the exact length but it does fill an entire screen when wrapped!

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. Appreciate your response.

Comment: btw I provided a sed solution also, please check.

Comment: sed solutions are frequently ugly.

Answer (score 1):

What if we reverse the string, change the FIRST occurrence in reversed string by sed, then reverse the result back to normal order:

```
#!/bin/bash

str="aaa bbb ccc bbb aaa"
echo "${str}" | rev | sed 's/bbb/zzz/' | rev
```

It works fine, if we need to replace just one symbol. For words, you need to reverse both, pattern and replacement words.